# Чтение и запись файла на С#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace LabThird
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("From.txt", Encoding.Default))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("To.txt"))
                {
                    string s;
                    while ((s = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

У меня есть код, для копирование текста файла и записи его в другой. Но мне необходимо во второй файл записать только слова не больше определенной длинны. Как мне узнать длину слова перед записью?

Входные данные в From.txt (длина слова должна быть <5)

> Hello World! My name is Gustavo
> But you can call me GUS.

Ожидаемый выход:

> My name is but you can call me GUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("From.txt"))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("To.txt"))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string s = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] words = s.Split();
            List<string> shortWords = new List<string>();
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (word.Length < 5)
                    shortWords.Add(word);
            }
            if (shortWords.Count > 0)
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", shortWords));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: нужно проверять длину слов, а не строк

Comment: @ВладиславКарпенко _Но мне необходимо во второй файл записать только слова не больше определенной длинны._ Как я должен был телепатически догадаться, что в строке больше одного слова? Чем разделены слова? Покажите пример входных и ожидаемых выходных данных.

Comment: Редактировал вопрос

Comment: @ВладиславКарпенко отредактировал ответ